# R - write.csv with fixed precision

Tags: r, precision

Is it possible to fix numbers precision, say 2 decimal digits, in `write.csv`? And if yes, is it possible to have integers stored without `.00` in this case? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not in `write.csv` or `write.table` itself. From the help document (`?write.table`):

> In almost all cases the conversion of numeric quantities is
>        governed by the option '"scipen"' (see 'options'), but with the
>        internal equivalent of 'digits = 15'.  For finer control, use
>        'format' to make a character matrix/data frame, and call
>        'write.table' on that.

What you may be better off doing is formatting the column(s) yourself using `format`, ala:

```
set.seed(42)
df1 <- data.frame(x = runif(10), y = sample(10))
df1$x <- round(df1$x, digits = 2)
write.csv(df1, ...)
```

***EDIT***:

For pretty-printing to the screen, just use `options(digits = 2)` and dump the data.frame again. I'm guessing you want to pretty-print into the CSV, so ...

Use the following function:

```
dfDigits <- function(x, digits = 2) {
    ## x is a data.frame
    for (col in colnames(x)[sapply(x, class) == 'numeric'])
        x[,col] <- round(x[,col], digits = digits)
    x
}
set.seed(42)
df1 <- data.frame(x=runif(5),y=sample(5))
head(df1)
##              x y
## 1 0.9148060435 3
## 2 0.9370754133 5
## 3 0.2861395348 1
## 4 0.8304476261 2
## 5 0.6417455189 4
head(dfDigits(df1, 2))
##      x y
## 1 0.91 3
## 2 0.94 5
## 3 0.29 1
## 4 0.83 2
## 5 0.64 4
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am aware of that option. I should have been more explicit - I add new columns to DF as I progress in the algorithm development, and it just becomes a bit of a nuisance to use the explicit `digits` for each numeric column. Wish there was just a subroutine for a DF that would convert all numeric columns to desired precision (or format) and keeping other types intact.

Comment: You want it implicit in `data.frame`? That's a different thing altogether than what you asked (about `write.csv`). So, what you are asking about is a function that will convert *all* numeric columns in a data.frame to a specific number of digits?

Comment: Only for writing out for "eye pleasing". Not for operations.

Comment: Oh cool! Your solution worked like a charm! Thank you very much. and it leaves integers intact. Much appreciated.